# The scene disappears at using Thread.sleep java

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, thread-sleep

I have created a map and I will not move any thing on it just make lines thick or thin Th problem is that I want to see the action so I used Thread.sleep();
But the whole scene then freezes the whole time and I can see nothing until time out so How can I fix that or what is the problem?

Comment: Are you running this in the main thread?

Comment: yes, in start() I call some other function and I want to suspend processing with that function

Answer (score 0):

You probably block the application thread.

Better do the animation using a `Timeline`:

```
Line line = ...
double startWidth = ...
double endWidth = ...

Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                          new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(line.strokeWidthProperty(), startWidth)),
                          new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(line.strokeWidthProperty(), endWidth)));
animation.play();
```